# How to calculate eccentricity of an Object in OpenCv Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on an image processing project based on android and I am stuck on a part and unable to move on.

I want to calculate the eccentricity of white pixel of an image but i am unsure how to calculate it.This metric value is also called as roundness or circularity or irregularity complex (I) equal to 1 only for circular and it is less than 1 for any other shape.

To calculate eccentricity i need the length of major axis and length of minor axis.

Eccentricity Formula:

[image: eccentricity formula]

May I have your advice on this please? Is there a way to implement a code in OpenCV java to find the eccentricity of an object?

My Input Image is :

[image: My Input Image is :]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output:]

Comment: First find the **bounding box** of your blob.Then, compute the eccentricity as `eccentricity = boundingBoxHeight / boundingBoxWidth`.

Comment: @eldesgraciado by finding the bounding box width and height, it gives the height and width of the rectangle which will be drawn around an object. I want to find the eccentricity of white area of image.